# E: unable to locate power managment interface

Tags: command-line, power-management

I am very new to Ubuntu
I am running Ubuntu 12.04

I tried to install the power management interface 
`sudo apt-get install power management interface`

and i get

> E: unable to locate power management interface

What does that mean
How should i fix it. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistyped the package name .You typed in `power management interface` when in actuality it should be: `powermanagement-interface`.

Type the following to install:

```
sudo apt-get install powermanagement-interface
```

Comment: I tried that still got the same error

Comment: I got it to work it said it was finished but it was frozen i couldn't switch to ctrl+alt+f1 so i had to hold the power switch when boot up it says system error press any key any key didn't work would the boot file have become corrupted.

Comment: Did complete reinstall tried it again and got the same error